# ARIMA forecast visualization

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, arima

I managed to make a forecast on a dataset of mine and everything works except for visualizing.
This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller

data = pd.read_excel ('file.xlsx',keep_default_na=False,index_col=0)


result = adfuller(data.Value.dropna())
print('ADF Statistic: %f' % result[0])
print('p-value: %f' % result[1])
```

Here I am using the adfuller test to see if the data is stationary.
And this is the result:

```
ADF Statistic: 0.724768
p-value: 0.990319
```

So in order to make it stationary I am going to difference to get rid of the trend and the seasonality.

```
# Plot
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(10,5), dpi=100, sharex=True)

# Usual Differencing
axes[0].plot(data[:], label='Original Series')
axes[0].plot(data[:].diff(1), label='Usual Differencing')
axes[0].set_title('Usual Differencing')
axes[0].legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=10)

# Seasinal Dei
axes[1].plot(data[:], label='Original Series')
axes[1].plot(data[:].diff(12), label='Seasonal Differencing', color='green')
axes[1].set_title('Seasonal Differencing')
plt.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=10)
plt.suptitle('Sales', fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

In the image below is shown that the data is stationary when I difference it.
[image: graph]

Next I am using auto_arima to fit the model.

```
smodel = auto_arima(data, start_p=1, start_q=1,
                         test='adf',
                         max_p=3, max_q=3, m=12,
                         start_P=0, seasonal=True,
                         d=None, D=1, trace=True,
                         error_action='ignore',  
                         suppress_warnings=True, 
                         stepwise=True)
```

At last I am doing a prediction:

```
# Forecast
n_periods = 5
fitted, confint = smodel.predict(n_periods=n_periods, return_conf_int=True)
index_of_fc = pd.date_range(data.index[-1], periods = n_periods, freq='MS')

# make series for plotting purpose
fitted_series = pd.Series(fitted, index=index_of_fc)
lower_series = pd.Series(confint[:, 0], index=index_of_fc)
upper_series = pd.Series(confint[:, 1], index=index_of_fc)

# Plot
plt.plot(data)
plt.plot(fitted_series, color='darkgreen')
plt.fill_between(lower_series.index, 
                 lower_series, 
                 upper_series, 
                 color='k', alpha=.15)

plt.title("SARIMA - Final Forecast of Sales")
plt.show()
```

But as you can see in the following image, there is a gap between the last date in the data which is 2019-10-01. The first data I am predicting should be 2019-11-01 but it puts it in 2019-10-01 again as you can see in the graph.

[image: sarima]

I am pretty sure it is because of this line:

```
index_of_fc = pd.date_range(data.index[-1], periods = n_periods, freq='MS')
```

But I do not know how to do it otherwise.

The data:

[image: data]
[image]

```
{'Value': {Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00'): 21,
  Timestamp('2015-02-01 00:00:00'): 19,
  Timestamp('2015-03-01 00:00:00'): 26,
  Timestamp('2015-04-01 00:00:00'): 30,
  Timestamp('2015-05-01 00:00:00'): 31,
  Timestamp('2015-06-01 00:00:00'): 36,
  Timestamp('2015-07-01 00:00:00'): 39,
  Timestamp('2015-08-01 00:00:00'): 40,
  Timestamp('2015-09-01 00:00:00'): 36,
  Timestamp('2015-10-01 00:00:00'): 27,
  Timestamp('2015-11-01 00:00:00'): 26,
  Timestamp('2015-12-01 00:00:00'): 31,
  Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00'): 23,
  Timestamp('2016-02-01 00:00:00'): 26,
  Timestamp('2016-03-01 00:00:00'): 31,
  Timestamp('2016-04-01 00:00:00'): 29,
  Timestamp('2016-05-01 00:00:00'): 33,
  Timestamp('2016-06-01 00:00:00'): 39,
  Timestamp('2016-07-01 00:00:00'): 41,
  Timestamp('2016-08-01 00:00:00'): 46,
  Timestamp('2016-09-01 00:00:00'): 35,
  Timestamp('2016-10-01 00:00:00'): 30,
  Timestamp('2016-11-01 00:00:00'): 27,
  Timestamp('2016-12-01 00:00:00'): 31,
  Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'): 28,
  Timestamp('2017-02-01 00:00:00'): 30,
  Timestamp('2017-03-01 00:00:00'): 32,
  Timestamp('2017-04-01 00:00:00'): 34,
  Timestamp('2017-05-01 00:00:00'): 38,
  Timestamp('2017-06-01 00:00:00'): 43,
  Timestamp('2017-07-01 00:00:00'): 49,
  Timestamp('2017-08-01 00:00:00'): 55,
  Timestamp('2017-09-01 00:00:00'): 39,
  Timestamp('2017-10-01 00:00:00'): 35,
  Timestamp('2017-11-01 00:00:00'): 32,
  Timestamp('2017-12-01 00:00:00'): 36,
  Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'): 36,
  Timestamp('2018-02-01 00:00:00'): 33,
  Timestamp('2018-03-01 00:00:00'): 40,
  Timestamp('2018-04-01 00:00:00'): 41,
  Timestamp('2018-05-01 00:00:00'): 50,
  Timestamp('2018-06-01 00:00:00'): 54,
  Timestamp('2018-07-01 00:00:00'): 62,
  Timestamp('2018-08-01 00:00:00'): 66,
  Timestamp('2018-09-01 00:00:00'): 47,
  Timestamp('2018-10-01 00:00:00'): 43,
  Timestamp('2018-11-01 00:00:00'): 36,
  Timestamp('2018-12-01 00:00:00'): 40,
  Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00'): 37,
  Timestamp('2019-02-01 00:00:00'): 35,
  Timestamp('2019-03-01 00:00:00'): 40,
  Timestamp('2019-04-01 00:00:00'): 48,
  Timestamp('2019-05-01 00:00:00'): 50,
  Timestamp('2019-06-01 00:00:00'): 58,
  Timestamp('2019-07-01 00:00:00'): 70,
  Timestamp('2019-08-01 00:00:00'): 70,
  Timestamp('2019-09-01 00:00:00'): 50,
  Timestamp('2019-10-01 00:00:00'): 46}}
```

All help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Do you mind to share your original data? Your question doesn't seem to contain a [mcve](/help/mcve) and there are no libraries imported.

Comment: I edited the data to the question! @rpanai

Comment: Do you mind to share the data as `df.to_dict()`?

Comment: @rpanai the libraries are imported at the top but it is not in the question! The only other part of the workbook is fitting the model but I did not think this was important since the problem is with the visual part.

Comment: @rpanai I edited the question with the .to_dict()

Comment: I edited the question adding imports you can check the edits history.

Comment: @rpanai thankyou for adding the imports! does the data I provided help with finding the problem?

Comment: It's still not reproducible.

Comment: @rpanai I have included the rest of the workbook, does this make it reproducible?

Comment: Am I wrong or you'd like to have have the last point in `data` and the first in fitted connected by a segment? If you can share `fitted`, `lower` and `upper` as `to_dict` I'd play with it. It's more a matter of plots and pandas rather than `arima`.

Comment: @rpanai yeah you are right, it is a matter of plots but I don't know what part I am doing wrong here. I am pretty sure this line": index_of_fc = pd.date_range(data.index[-1], periods = n_periods, freq='MS') takes the last value minus 1 and thats why it doesn't show the predicted date in the graph but the last date of the data. Could I be right?

Answer (score 0):

it will work for you:
index_of_fc = pd.date_range(data.index[-1], periods = n_periods+1, freq='MS')
index_of_fc = index_of_fc[1:]

Comment: Just tried it, this solution did not work.